# How to handle the exceptions after throwing them in main method?

Tags: java, exception

Is there any higher method that can catch and handle the exception occurs in the main method?

How can we deal with it?

Here is an example given by *Introduction to Java Programming* (in Chapter 12)

```
//Listing 12.13 WriteData.java
class WriteData {
 public static void main(String[] args) **throws IOException** {
    java.io.File file = new java.io.File("scores.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
      System.out.println("File already exists");
      System.exit(1);
    }

    // Create a file
    java.io.PrintWriter output = new java.io.PrintWriter(file);

    // Write formatted output to the file
    output.print("John T Smith ");
    output.println(90);
    output.print("Eric K Jones ");
    output.println(85);

    // Close the file
    output.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can choose between capture the exception and treat it in the same method with try{} catch{} statements or, throw it like the example and then capture it in other method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever *any* thread throws an exception that's not handled anywhere in its call stack then an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` present on the the `Thread` (see [`Thread.setUncaughtExceptionHandler`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler))) will be invoked. This applies not just to the default `main` thread, but to every one that's manually created. By default the `main` thread doesn't have an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`.

If the `Thread` doesn't have one, then the `ThreadGroup` handles it, as describd in [`ThreadGroup.uncaughtException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException(java.lang.Thread,java.lang.Throwable)).

This demonstrates what a simple exception handler would look like:

```
class ExceptionHandlerSample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler());
    ((Object) null).toString(); // force a NullPointerException to be thrown.
  }
}

class MyExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
  @Override
  public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
    System.out.printf("Thread %s threw an exception of type %s: %s",
        t.getName(), e.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage());
  }
}
```